# Woocommerce - Remove moderate_comments Capability from Shop Manager

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove the `moderate_comments` capability from the Shop Manager Role.

I am using the below code, which is not working at all.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_hgkb_caps');
function add_hgkb_caps() {
    $shop_manager = get_role( 'shop_manager' );
    $shop_manager->remove_cap('moderate_comments');
}
```

However the same is working fine with other roles, like editor, and author.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different Method:-

```
add_filter( 'comment_row_actions', 'add_hgkb_caps', 15, 2 );
function add_hgkb_caps( $actions, $comment )
{
    $roles=array('shop_manager'); //You can add more roles
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_role=$current_user->roles[0];

    if(in_array($current_user_role,$roles))
    {
        unset( $actions['quickedit'], $actions['edit'], $actions['spam'], $actions['unspam'], $actions['trash'], $actions['untrash'], $actions['approve'], $actions['unapprove'], $actions['delete'] );
    }
    return $actions;
}
```